# Bootstrap 3 responsive col in a row - how to?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, row

So i have a row with 2 or 3 different col's inside. I want it to be like on this site : http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0196957
On featured. There are those 3 images with text and when i minimize my browser they'll be aligned under each one not besides each one.

So how do i do that?

I tried it like this but this won't work when i minimize the browser because the things will overlap because they're in one row.

```
<div class="container dates-sub">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="day-sub">28</span>
            <span class="month-sub">09</span>
            <span class="year-sub">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
            <span class="day-sub">30</span>
            <span class="month-sub">10</span>
            <span class="year-sub">2015</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="blog-title">
                <h3 class="blog-heading">NASA-ESA Space Festival San Francisco</h3>
                <p class="blog-dates">28.09.2015, 19:00, Hohenzollernring 56,<br>50672 Köln, Germany <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-sub">
                <p>Dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam vol paxo
                    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea ruits-
                    clita kasd gubergren.

                    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
                    ea clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanda-
                    ipsum dolor sit amet. Dolore magna aliquyam e-
                    rat, sed diam vol paxo eos et accusam et justo
                    duo dolores et ea.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="blog-title">
                <h3 class="blog-heading">Benefit-Gala</h3>
                <p class="blog-dates">30.10.2015, 19:00, Hohenzollernring 56,<br>50672 Köln, Germany <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-sub">
                <p>Dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam vol paxo
                    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea ruits-
                    clita kasd gubergren.

                    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
                    ea clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanda-
                    ipsum dolor sit amet. Dolore magna aliquyam e-
                    rat, sed diam vol paxo eos et accusam et justo
                    duo dolores et ea. At vero eos et accusam et ju-
                    sto duo dolores etea clita kasd gubergren, no s-
                    ea takimata sandaipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your example contains no images.

Comment: Yes, that's custom css doing that position change: stacked images and text next to it. It can be done, maybe, with just the grid classes, but I wouldn't bother adding more html for a simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you've tried to put your images, but as long as you put them in a "thumbnail" class like so, `<div class="thumbnail"><img src="..."></div>` they should not overlap.

Than apply a `col-xs-6 col-md-12 and` to change the top/bottom orientation of the caption to left/right.

See an example: http://www.bootply.com/h6STovl9Qq

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're using these layouts :

- `4 / (+2)4` for the first line (`.col-md-4` + `.col-md-offet-2.col-md-4`)
- `6 / 6` for the second line (`.col-md-6` + `.col-md-6`)

You need to know several things about Bootstrap:

- `md` means "medium" (ie. devices larger than 992px, and thinner than 1200px)
- Bootstrap is **mobile first**, which means it'll try to render the e**x**tra-**s**mall layout first, then **sm**all, then **m**e**d**ium, then **l**ar**g**e.
- Wihout any column classes used, Bootstrap will use the 12-column class.

This means you have not any column classes set for **extra-small** and **small** devices. In this case, Bootstrap render them as 12-columns elements, which explains they're taking the full row.

To get your layout to work on **every** device, you need to use the smallest column class as possible, `.col-xs-xx`:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container dates-sub">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span class="day-sub">28</span>
            <span class="month-sub">09</span>
            <span class="year-sub">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-4">
            <span class="day-sub">30</span>
            <span class="month-sub">10</span>
            <span class="year-sub">2015</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="blog-title">
                <h3 class="blog-heading">NASA-ESA Space Festival San Francisco</h3>
                <p class="blog-dates">28.09.2015, 19:00, Hohenzollernring 56,<br>50672 Köln, Germany <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-sub">
                <p>Dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam vol paxo
                    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea ruits-
                    clita kasd gubergren.

                    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
                    ea clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanda-
                    ipsum dolor sit amet. Dolore magna aliquyam e-
                    rat, sed diam vol paxo eos et accusam et justo
                    duo dolores et ea.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="blog-title">
                <h3 class="blog-heading">Benefit-Gala</h3>
                <p class="blog-dates">30.10.2015, 19:00, Hohenzollernring 56,<br>50672 Köln, Germany <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-sub">
                <p>Dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam vol paxo
                    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea ruits-
                    clita kasd gubergren.

                    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
                    ea clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanda-
                    ipsum dolor sit amet. Dolore magna aliquyam e-
                    rat, sed diam vol paxo eos et accusam et justo
                    duo dolores et ea. At vero eos et accusam et ju-
                    sto duo dolores etea clita kasd gubergren, no s-
                    ea takimata sandaipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please read bootstrap documentation

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

In you want to force element to look same as on big screens you have to add them other responsive classes like this

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Hello</div>
```

Or if you are using less you can do something like this

```
.my-class{
 .make-lg-column(6);
 .make-md-column(6);
 .make-sm-column(6);
 .make-xs-column(6);
}

<div class="my-class">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Your first example is extremely redundant; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Comment: @cvrebert That why you gave me vote down? I shoq when using LESS better solution??